# Update column using arcpy

Tags: arcpy

I have to update a rank column from 1-5  based on the category field.
For example if my category is COMGOV assign rank 1
If category is HOTPRE OR RCNCLB or HOTRES assign rank 2
If category is COMBAN or HLTSPA or so on assign rank I need to run this using arcpy script...

```
import arcpy
Tl= "D:/Shreya/DL.shp"
fields = ["FTR_CRY", "RANK"]
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(Tl, fields) as cursor:
   for row in cursor:
      if row[0] =="COMGOV":
         row[1] = 1
      cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: import arcpy

Tl= "D:/Shreya/DL.shp"
fields = ["FTR_CRY", "RANK"]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(Tl, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if  row[0] =="COMGOV":
            row[1] = 1
            cursor.updateRow(row)

Comment: Your code should work, just add some `elif` statements for other categories. Or do you get an error message?